# Jquery / Javascript get params from window localtion

Tags: javascript, jquery

My URL is:

```
http://localhost:3000/?sort=rating
```

The parameter `sort` is dynamic, and I would like to add it to another URL.

In my javascript I have:

```
window.location.pathname + '.js?page=' + currentPage
```

How do I add the `sort` parameter at the end?

Example:

```
window.location.pathname + '.js?page=' + currentPage + &sortparam
```

In this case it would be:

```
window.location.pathname + '.js?page=' + currentPage + '&sort=rating'
```

Comment: Do you want to just replace the `?` with a `&` or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: I just want to include the params sort in the ajax call.

Comment: I found at that I can use window.location.search but then I need to replace the ? with &

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you're looking for:

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

In your case:

```
function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var sortparam = getParameterByName("sort");
window.location.pathname + '.js?page=' + currentPage + '&sort='+sortparam
```

Comment: is it safe, thinking of someone could escape javascript in the param?

Comment: there is a little typo "'&sort='sortparam" it should be "'&sort=' + sortparam

Comment: I don't know your sort algorithm and what exactly you're doing with the sortparam. But value's in the javascript-code can EVER be changed by the user. (Chrome extension, firebug,...)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one more, with a slightly more general wrapper:

```
function getParams() {

  var params = window.location.search.substring(1).split('& '),
    i = 0,
    pair = null,
    result = {};

  while (pair = params[i++]) {
    pair = pair.split('=');
    result[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
  }

  return result;
}

alert(getParams().page);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.pathname + '.js?page=' + currentPage +
    "&" + location.search.match(/(sort=.*?)&|$/)[1]
```